# LOB Windows store App Quality and Crash Reports

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am working with LOB windows store app, which will not go to the store, it will be used by the company employees. My Question, Is there any way to report when the app crash? , something like the app dashboard when the app is published to the store.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd party library to get log about crash and exception. I have used [MarkedUp](https://markedup.com/). Another way is to create own web service which sends crash log to some database.